# ListPlot is Mathematica without storing the list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm looking for a way to generate and plot data without storing the actual data. As a basic example:

```
list = {}; idim = 40; ndiag = 100; grpSize = 4; m = idim/grpSize;
For[rank = 0, rank < grpSize, rank++,
 For[j = rank*m, j < (rank + 1)*m, j++,
  For[k = 0, k < ndiag, k++,
   For[l = 0, l < ndiag, l++,
    AppendTo[list, {k + ndiag*j, l + ndiag*j}]
    ]]]]
ListPlot[list]
```

As it is, this takes quite a long time. Presumably because of the constant additions to the list that have to be stored. It starts of quick, but as the list gets long it slows down. I really only want to see the pattern that gets filled in. Is there a way to avoid storing the list and just add points one at a time to the plot? It doesn't have to display it as it's updated, one plot when it's done is fine. EDIT: I did find Reap and Sow, which definitely help a ton with the speed issue, but out of sheer curiosity I'd still like to find out how to avoid storing the data at all (except as the plot).

Answer (score 2):

Before you start wrestling with animated plots and the like, I suggest you re-write the lines which generate your dataset.  You have written what appears to be a C program using Mathematica, and have chosen what is probably the slowest approach to creating a list of data.

I don't have Mathematica on this machine so haven't tested the following, but a statement along the lines of:

```
tabl = Table[{k + ndiag*j, l + ndiag*j}, {l,0,ndiag-1},{k,0,ndiag-1},{j,rank*m,(rank+1)*m},{rank,0,grpSize-1}]
```

will run much faster (I mean, much faster) than your nest of loops. You'll find the output from the `Table` execution needs a bit of `Flatten`-ing. In passing I'd also note that it is more natural in Mathematica to use 1 as the index base, than to use 0.

I believe that you are correct to identify your use of `Append` as the culprit in making your code slow.  This is a topic that has been covered several times on SO, I think that Mathematica is reallocating memory every time you `Append` to an existing list

I think that the `Table` command will run quickly enough that your desire to have the plot generated step-by-step will evaporate.  But if it does not you could look at `Animate` or one of its cousins.  If you are not careful, though, you might find that you take memory for the list of data points at each stage, so instead of a Table having N items, you find yourself with a series of Tables with sizes `1, 2, 3, ..., N` which would not be much of an optimisation.

I think that your idea of adding points to a plot one at a time in an effort to save memory is misconceived -- where (and how) will the information for the plot be stored until you display it ?  Have a look at the `FullForm` of a simple graphic.

If you are still concerned about memory usage then either `Remove` the variable you create after your are finished with it, or simply wrap `ListPlot[]` around the `Table` statement, in which case the table won't have a name so will be garbage collected when Mathematica gets round to it.  I'm not convinced that Mathematica is spectacularly good at garbage collection, but I rarely worry about it either.

Comment: Actually I meant that I *don't* need animated plots. The Table is a good suggestion. Reap and Sow made the actual generation of data trivial, so speed isn't bad now. My desire to avoid storing the data may have been misworded. I'm curious if I can avoid storing it twice. Currently, I end up with a list of data points, and a graphic that has that same list of data points. I want to essentially create a single plot, then be able to incorporate new data into the plot directly.

It is, in fact, C++ code, actually. I'm plotting the fill structure of a matrix so I can see if it's behaving correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do the data and plot in the screenshots below look like what your are trying to get?

```
   list = Table[Table[Table[{k + ndiag j, l + ndiag j}, {k, 0, ndiag}, {l, 0, ndiag}], 
   {j, rank m , (rank + 1) m}], 
   {rank, 0, grpSize}] //  Flatten[#, 3] &
```

generates the data

[image: data]

and

```
  ListPlot[list]
```

gives

[image]